# Using db_query() or db_select() to connect to multiple databases

Tags: 7, database

How can I execute a query that connects to different databases?

I have the following query, and I need to rewrite it for Drupal.

```
SELECT a.empid, b.empname FROM db1..empidmaster a, db2..emplist b
WHERE a.empid = b.empid
```

How can I rewrite the query using `db_query()`, or `db_select()`?

Comment: You can set multiple database access information in settings.php and db_set_active() to switch the database connection (Don't forget to set it back to default!!!) but single query through multiple databases is not possible AFAIK.

Answer (score 9):

If the settings.php file defines the information to connect to the other database as `$databases['extra']['default']`, then you can use the following code, which is possible because [SelectQuery::join()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3a%3ajoin/7) accepts also another `SelectQuery` object as `$table` argument.

```
$subquery = Database::getConnection('default', 'extra')->select('emplist', 'b');
$query = db_select('empidmaster', 'a');
$query->join($subquery, 'b', 'b.empid = a.empid');
$query->addField('a', 'empid');
$query->addField('b', 'empname');
```

A better code would be similar to the following one. In this case the alias used for the table used for the subquery is the one returned from `SelectQuery::join()`.

```
$subquery = Database::getConnection('default', 'extra')->select('emplist', 'b');
$query = db_select('empidmaster', 'a');
$alias = $query->join($subquery, 'b', '%alias.empid = a.empid');
$query->addField('a', 'empid');
$query->addField($alias, 'empname');
```

`SelectQuery::join()`, and `SelectQuery::addField()` don't return the `$query` object; that is the reason you cannot the following code.

```
$query = db_select('empidmaster', 'a')
  ->join($subquery, 'b', 'b.empid = a.empid')
  ->addField('a', 'empid')
  ->addField('b', 'empname');
```

PHP would return an error about a method not being called on an object. In fact, `SelectQuery::join()` and `SelectQuery::addField()` return a string: the alias for the table, or the field.

Comment: Can you really do that? That's awesome!

Comment: It's documented in [SelectQuery::addJoin()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AaddJoin/7), the method for which `SelectQuery::join()` is a wrapper. It would be better if the documentation for `SelectQuery::join()` would remind that too.

Comment: This code doesn't work for me, I also have prefixes in one of the databases... but that's not the main problem, it's still trying to get the "extra" database under the name of the "default" one... did you face this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If both database are in the same server and same user, you can do this:

`db_query("SELECT a.empid, b.empname FROM {empidmaster} a JOIN database2.emplist b ON b.empid = a.empid");`

Table `a` represents drupal database, and `b`, the external database.