# Target different database for a single query?

Tags: database

Can I set the target database on a [db_select()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7)?

Example:

```
$result = db_select('table', 't')->fields('t')->db_target('db_name')->execute();
```

One can use [db_set_active()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7) to change to which database a query should be sent, but that requires one to manually "reset" the active db, which is a potential cause of bugs.

Comment: I've never come across any bugs with `db_set_active()`, could you elaborate a wee bit?

Comment: I haven't entirely figured out what happened, but it seemed like a query against db A triggered a hook, that made a module want to translate a string, which made locale try to lookup translations, which fails because locale_source is in db B. I had to hack a `db_set_actice('default')` into locale.module to work around it. Made me think it would be useful to set the target per query instead of per connection.

Comment: Wow that sounds like fun! I'm not sure but maybe the code in Kiamlaluno's answer to [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45199/how-to-write-db-query-or-db-select-from-multiple-databases-in-drupal-7/45542#45542) will help? The questions don't match but there's a technique in there for selecting from arbitrary databases that I hadn't seen before

Comment: Hmm, interesting, I will have to try it next time this problem bites me. Thanks @Clive.

Answer (score 3):

From the comments above such as from @Clive, I do this alll the time:

```
$count_query = Database::getConnection('default', 'dew_remote_sources')
               ->select('survey', 's');
$count_query->addExpression('COUNT(DISTINCT(survey_number))', 'cnt');
```

For this to work you need to have various databases defined in your `$databases` value of settings.php (or you can add additional `$databases[key]` values to top of your module sometimes, or create such a connection on-the-fly using:

```
Database::addConnectionInfo('for_migration', 'default', array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'migration_database',
  'username' => 'username',
  'password' => 'password',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'prefix' => '',
));
```

You see this pattern alot in the [Migrate](http://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) [documentation pages](http://drupal.org/node/1014558), migrate examples and 3rd party modules that have implemented migrations. Because you are literally moving content from DatabaseX to DatabaseY alot and switching around with `db_set_active` can easily lead to confusion in such cases with the Object Oriented nature of the Migrate module.

Comment: This is probably one of the most useful things I have seen on this site.  Cheers!