# Join 2 databases

Tags: database

I would like to join 2 tables in 2 different databases in using their id.

```
$new_url = "SELECT * FROM {one.url_alias} a
    INNER JOIN (one_old.url_alias} b
    ON a.pid = b.pid";
  print_r($new_url);
```

But I'm not getting any results. I did configured 2 databases in settings.php

```
$databases = array (
  'default' =>
  array (
    'default' =>
    array (
      'database' => 'one',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
  'external' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'one_old',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think your question might already be answered here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45199/using-db-query-or-db-select-to-connect-to-multiple-databases